# TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

После установки node-sass у меня вышла ошибка TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function показывающая ошибку в файле node-sass/lib/extensions.js это >

```
function hasBinary(binaryPath) {
  return fs.existsSync(binaryPath);
}
```

Я не понимаю, почему он возмущается, почему не считает это функций

Comment: Покажите что вы делаете до возникновения ошибки

Comment: @MaxNest Делал подключение файлов для авторизации. Терминал затребовал установить node-sass. Я его установил. Какая ошибка была -> "./src/containers/Quiz/Quiz.module.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-6-4!./src/containers/Quiz/Quiz.module.scss)
To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass.
Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace."

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Отредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос по шагам: как вы установили, были ли при этом ошибки, какой код вы запустили, какие ошибки возникли...